# How to create an object of another class to access the class's variables in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Like in objective C we create an object of a class to access that class's variable -

```
TableViewCell *obj = [[TableViewCell alloc] init];
```

then using "obj" we can access the variables of the class.

Similarly, I have a property of an `UIView` in a `TableViewCell`'s class and I want to access that in the main class of the `ViewController` in which the table view is present.

I have tried doing this -

```
let viewObj = ViewAllCell()
```

**Inside viewDidLoad**

```
viewObj.menuView.isHidden = true;
```

But just as this code executes I get the following error

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value"

I know this question must have been asked a million times before but I didn't understand what to search for in Swift as I'm quite new to this language, hence I am asking again.

Comment: share the code you have tried and the error stacktrace.

Comment: `ViewAllCell()` creates a new instance of the class. It is not related to other instances used in the table view.

Comment: @AnilKumar That's the whole error I am getting. In the rest of the code I'm just configuring the tableview(Delegate, DataSource methods and all).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with respect to accessing the variable.
The menuView variable is an optional variable and it's set to nil.

**Case 1:**
If you're sure that every ViewAllCell should have a menuView, don't make it an optional. Your current code will look something like:

**ViewAllCell.swift**

```
internal var menuView : MenuView? = nil
```

Change that to:

```
internal var menuView : MenuView = MenuView(frame:<yourRequiredframe>)
```

Either set the frame here, or just instatiate with menuView = MenuView(), and set it later.

**Case 2:**

If you want the menuView to be optional, instantiate a menuView in your viewDidLoad()

**viewDidLoad()**

```
let viewObj = ViewAllCell()
viewObj.menuView = MenuView(frame:<yourRequiredframe>)
viewObj.menuView.isHidden = true;
```

If you want to know a lot, lot more about optionals, wrapping, unwrapping, and guard statements, have a look at this:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2469047&seqNum=2

Answer (score -1):

no need to create object to Access class variable.

According to obj C => `clasname.staticVariable`
/**********************/

```
UITableViewCell *fontCell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[_tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]]
    UIView *view =  Font.view;
```

But view Cannot be static

Comment: Yeah just like that! Now I have a property of a uiview inside a tableviewcell's class. How do I access that in the main view controller class ?